# When I deploy the web application in the GlassFish server then that server is displaying the following error message

Tags: glassfish

When I deploy the web application in the GlassFish server then that server is displaying the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain domain1
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\
    domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:209)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:238) 
Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

    Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
    ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: 
        org.osgi.framework; version=1.6.0,
        org.osgi.framework.launch; version=1.0.0, 
        org.osgi.framework.wiring; version=1.0.0,
        org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0,    
        org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version=1.0.0,           
        org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0.0,
        org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.1.0,          
        org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.0.0,
        org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2.0,
        org.osgi.service.startlevel; version=1.1.0,
        org.osgi.service.url; version=1.0.0,
        org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.0, ,   
    org.glassfish.embeddable;org.glassfish.embeddable.spi;version=3.1.1 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)
    ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish-      3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
    ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Unable to create cache directory.)
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:729)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:220)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:374)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher.launchOSGiFrameWork(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:77)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:128)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException:     

    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:634)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        ... 1 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
    Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException:     

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:230)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:133)
        ... 9 more
    Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:203)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option     
    MaxPermSize=192m;     

    support was removed in 8.0
    Java Hotot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m;    

    support was removed in 8.0

    Command start-domain failed.

    C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\bin>
```

Comment: Did you try checking access permissions on the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a GlassFish expert, but normally you read stack traces from bottom to top.
The topmost error message is therefore the most detailed one.
The topmost error message in this stack trace is:
 `file.AccessDeniedException`
on the file
 `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\ domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck`

I also see in the second part of the log:
 `ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix`

It looks to me like a file permissions problem, or a directory that is expected to be there that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You have use command line as administrator for connecting to server. You should get the next:

command-1:

```
cd C:\Program Files\glassfish4.1\glassfish\bin //Here your glassfish bin directory
```

command-2:

```
asadmin start-domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look at the directory correctly - this worked for me

> `C:\GLASSFISH_HOME\bin>` asadmin start-domain domain1
> Waiting for domain1 to start ............
> Waiting finished after 11,396 ms.
> Successfully started the domain : domain1
> domain  Location: C:\GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\domains\domain1
> Log File: C:\GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
> Admin Port: 4,848
> Command start-domain executed successfully.